# If I "randomly" come up with curve, how do I obtain it's parametrization?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, parametrization

Sorry If this question is too cumbersome, I am still a bit lost at the basics of differential geometry: Given the curve $(\cos t,\sin 3t)$, how to obtain the parametrization of this curve? I've been thinking about using the relation $\tilde\gamma(t)=\gamma(\phi(t))$ and comparing it with the arc length parametrization. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: that one it is already parametrized and its arcparamentrization ought to be reached thru $l=\int\sqrt{\sin^2t+3\cos^23t}dt$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, you are a bit confused. You probably need to do some reading. But here are a few hints to get you started.

You ask how you can find a parametrization for a given curve. If the curve is given in implicit form, i.e. $F(x,y)=0$, it may not be possible to parametrize it. Not all curves can be parametrized.

You ask about *the* parametrization of a curve. But any curve that has a parametrization actually has several. You can just compose a given parametrization with another function (preferably monotone) to get a new parametrization.

The curve you gave as an example is already in parametric form. The function $t \mapsto (\cos t, \sin 3t)$ already **is** a parametrization.

Maybe what you’re trying to find is an *arclength* parameterization. Given any random parametric curve, you can construct an arclength parametrization, but it’s going to involve integrals that can hardly ever be expressed via simple formulas.

Comment: Not to mention finding the inverse function of said integral …